# How can I tell Flash Builder 4 where to look for FlashPlayer.exe

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder

I uninstalled Flash Builder Beta 2 and installed the Flash Builder 4. I tried to import my new projects, but I keep getting a popup that says:

"
[path/to/Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2/FlashPlayer.exe]

Flash Builder cannot locate the required version of Adobe Flash Player.

Do you want to try to run your application with the current version?

[Adobe Flash Player downloads](http://adobe.com/go/flashplayer_debugger)"

I have a run config on a localhost server instead of generating the html wrapper. This only happens with imported projects, but I can't seem to find where in any of the config files the player location is specified.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer, but...

Instead of importing projects into a new workspace; have you tried using the same workspace?  You can specify the workspace using the data argument when you launch Flash Builder:

```
flashbuilder.exe data="C:\something\something\something\workspace"
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to launch Flash builder with the '`-clean`' command line argument.  I've found that fixes a lot of the issues I have.

Also check your SDK on the imported projects.  Make sure it is not pointed at an old SDK from the beta 2 directory.  After you change the SDK, be sure to clean the project.

Or if none of that works, re-create the project from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the answer, or at least will help me solve this ~3 hour headache. There are just too many variables that could affect it. But I _am_ using Flex 3.4.1... which isn't the default for Flash Builder 4, but is for Flex Builder Beta 2. Testing...